# if statement and $_GET

Tags: php, if-statement, get

I am passing a variable using GET, and I'd like a fallback if there's nothing there. I've been using

```
$page = $_get;
if $page = ""
 {
  include 'home.php';
 }
else
 {
  include $page;
 }
```

But it just breaks my page. Any ideas?

Comment: I think you'd want to use if($_GET['varName']){...}

Comment: it's not `$_get` it's `$_GET`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably just missing the parens on the if statement. Also, you'll need to specify the GET param.

```
$page = $_GET['param'];

if ($page == "") {
    include 'home.php';
} else {
    include $page;
}
```

Comment: You should probably check to see if `$_GET['param']` is set before assigning it to `$page`

Comment: His question was about a fall back. It's either the "nothing there" or everything else. Set or not is irrelevant. I hope you weren't the down vote.

Comment: You're a star, thank you so much. I know it's just something silly, but I'm learning this with little-no-time before the work is due. Thanks.

Comment: It would be wise to review some of the other answers, too. I simply answered your question, but, there are serious other concerns with that snippet of code, namely: Security and the functionality that you probably wanted but didn't articulate. Also, thanks to the down voter! I appreciate that!

Answer (score 3):

**First**, `$_GET` is in capitals.

**Second**, you need to say which `value_name` you want. `$_GET['value_name']`

**Third**, you need to check if the `value_name` has been set. `if(isset($_GET['value_name']))`

**Fourth**, and most important: **NEVER DO THIS** ! Never include files based on what is given in the url or otherwise user input. You **will** be [hacked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20332220/got-hacked-what-does-this-php-code-do-and-how-should-i-avoid/20332249#20332249) ! Rather you match the given value to an array of allowed file names or use a `switch`.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, `$_GET` is an associative array. So you should check against something, or not empty.

On the other hand, here `$page = ""` you're assigning; if you want to compare, you need to use `==` or `===`. Also, you could use functions like [isset](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php), or [empty](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php), that will return you a bool if there is an element or not in the variable.

So, what you need is something like this

```
include !empty($_GET['param'])?$_GET['param']:'home.php'
```

[? is a ternary operator](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php), is a resumed if-else

As last aclaration, you should never include directly variables you receive from $_GET, and $_POST. This will put risk on your system. [example on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15183814/avoiding-using-include-getpage)

Answer (score 0):

Also, use `isset()` to check if you have an input...

But yes what you want to do is a little bit dangerous in term of security... !